# Creating multiple objects using a for loop

Tags: java

I'm having difficulty in creating multiple objects in a for loop the object keeps being overwritten each time the loop is run.

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
Driver one = new Driver();
}
```

How do I make it so that new objects are created every time the loop is run, currently one just keeps being overwritten.

Sorry for the basic question i'm just new to programming.

Comment: Put it in an array?

Comment: It says problem converting Driver to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using **array**:

```
int n = 10;
Driver[] driverArray = new Driver[n];
for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
    driverArray[i]= new Driver();
}
```

In your code, you are declaring a local reference to Driver class, and creating new Driver object in every iteration.
It doesn't work for two reasons:
  **1.** You are declaring local reference in for-loop so the only place, when you can use it is this for-loop.
  **2.** Even if you declare the reference outside the loop you would initialize it with new Driver object so after loop you would have the only one Driver insance - the last one.
For more about **arrays** you can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but its still giving me an error of converting the driver to int

Comment: Driver is not the type of int or Integer. If you want to work with integers you should repleace Driver in your code with Integer: "Integer[] driverArray = new Integer[n]", and driverArray[i] = new Integer(i);